# angular.js: using events to trigger actions in controllers might cause memory leak

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

My application is structured as follows:
- a static header with a search box and button
- a menu in the header which switches between views
- below that, a div with ng-view; the views are switched on menu click via routeProvider

When the user clicks the search button in the header, all view controllers (assigned via routeProvider) should load some data from a shared service. I implemented this using events. In my search form controller:

```
$scope.search = function () {
        DataStore.load($scope.searchFormState.someSearchParam, $scope.searchFormState.anotherSearchParam);
        $scope.$emit('searchForm:search');
    }
```

In my controllers I listen to that event and load some data:

```
$scope.systemListener = $rootScope.$on('searchForm:search', function () {
        DataStore.promises.somePromise.then(function () {
            $scope.myDataArray = DataStore.data.dataArrayFromService;
        });
    });
```

Then, in my controllers, I listen for the destroy event:

```
    $scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
        $scope.systemListener();
    });
```

Everything works fine, but when I click around in the menu, I notice that my js heap grows fast. I suspect that there is a memory leak somewhere. Could it be related to scope from my controllers not being properly garbage collected? Would I have to do anything else in my destructor function?

Comment: $scope.$$listener=[]; will remove all traces of the subscription..
and actually `$scope.systemListener();` is perfectly fine..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the memory leak might have actually been a bug in Chrome dev tools (details can be found here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4864).
In my particular case, this is no longer an issue, because my application has undergone a complete rewrite and the memory consumption is much better now.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any watchers in your controller, you might want to unwatch them in $destroy listener.
Like `

```
var $unwatch = scope.$watch(something, somethingElse);

$scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
    $unwatch();
});
```

Also, I would recommend not using `$scope.$$listener = [];` in your code, at least since `$$listener` is a local variable of angularjs, and it's name might change with upcoming versions of angular.

Comment: Thanks, that's actually what I'm doing (see the "systemListener" in my code example).